# CSS specificity and deprecated HTML attributes

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

What would be the implied [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) of the following style applied, if any:

```
<iframe src="..." height="300" width="500"></iframe>
```

Does it still get `specificity = 1,0,0,0` and override any other style applied? How would that work together with *proper* inline styles, i.e. which would take precedence:

```
<iframe src="..." height="300" width="500" style="height:150px;width:600px;"></iframe>
```

Did browsers agree to prefer `style=""` declarations over invalid ones, or is there something else going on?

**NB**: I'm simply curious about the mechanics of selecting the correct styles to be applied in this scenario, but do not advocate such declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specificity of CSS rules to which presentational HTML attributes may be mapped is zero (0), according to the last section on the page you referred to, [Precedence of non-CSS presentational hints](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint). Thus, settings in the real style sheet of a page override such attributes, e.g. `style="height:150px;width:600px;"` wins the `height` and `width` attributes.

This does not depend on the validity of the attributes. Validity is a formal thing and does not affect browser behavior. Even if you declare a Strict doctype, browsers will still honor those presentational attributes that they recognize. (There is no specification on this. It’s just how things work.)

P.S. The example in the section may look odd. Why doesn’t `font[color] { color: orange; }` in a user style sheet affect `font` elements with `color` attributes in HTML documents? The reason is that the attributes are translated to CSS rules in the *author* (page) style sheet, and (in the absence of `!important`) anything in an author style sheet wins a *user* style sheet. But `font[color] { color: orange; }` in an *author* style sheet would  override the color set in markup like `<font color=red>`.

Comment: If they are mapped with a specificity of 0, does it mean these values will be overridden by *any* non-`*` rule? i.e. if in the first example above I also had `iframe {height:1000px;}` in the stylesheet, *that* would be the value rendered? I believe that's exactly what the spec points to, but for some reason it feels counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: It means that the value will be overridden by any CSS rule in an author style sheet, even a rule using the universal selector `*`. For example, `<font color=blue>` is overridden by `* { color: red }`. Perhaps unintuitive if you think of presentational attributes as specific styling, but the point is that they are in a different world, HTML vs. CSS. *Any* presentational HTML attribute is specific to the element it is attached to. But the CSS specificity concept is a different thing, constructed to set up cascade rules.

Answer (score 0):

The `style=""` attribute and/or any css declaration will always have precedence over the `width` and `height` html attributes.

In any case it's always recommended to use CSS stylesheets.

Comment: could you provide some specs/docos to back that up? I wonder where and how this behaviour would be defined. I mean, there's still legacy support for deprecated attributes like `width` and `height` and it's probably not going away for a while :)